# Abrir el contenido de link externo en modal Bootsatrap

Tags: bootstrap

Tengo el siguiente código que abre una página `php` en un modal de Bootstrap, esta funcional sin problemas.

```
<div class="bs-example">
<a href="abrirxml.php" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Launch Demo Modal</a>
<!-- Modal HTML -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade">
   <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
         <!-- Content will be loaded here from "remote.php" file -->
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
</div>
```

El problema surge cuando quiere mostrar una página `php` que se genera cuando se le llama, osea cuando le doy click al enlace se busca la información y se genera la tabla y la página, cuando trato de abrirla por medio del modal no hace nada, me parece que no tiene nada que mostrar.

Comment: le estás pasando al modal la vista de esa página para que pueda mostrarla?

Comment: @SergioGutiérrez a que te refieres con que le paso la vista de esa página? Como mencionaba con una página fija si lo muestra,